# join query in same table

Tags: mysql

i dont know how to ask this question in proper english.

i have a query

```
select * from user
```

it return

```
id, username, status, owner_id
```

when i print

```
1 - john - 1 - 0
2 - paul - 1 - 0
3 - adam - 1 - 1 (where adam is owned by john)
4 - tony - 1 - 2 (where tony is owned by paul)
```

my problem is i want to print owner name

i tried

```
select * from users
foreach($r as $row){
echo $row['id'];
echo $row['username'];
//inside here i did a second select
select username from users where id = $row['owner_id'] 
}
```

problem is because the database is really big it get max_execution time.

is there better way to do this?

thanks

Comment: You have many [unclosed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1135591/alvaro-louzada?tab=questions), right? Please have look to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 Thanks for all your answerers and future readers :)

Comment: I dont how this works, i have to click the check icon for the answer when its ok?

Comment: Yes, absolutely :) You could also upvote if some anwsers helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`LEFT JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) on the same table with aliases :

```
select u1.id as u1id, u1.name as u1name, u1.status as u1status,
       u2.id as u2id, u2.name as u2name, u2.status as u2status
from users u1
left join users u2 on u2.id = u1.onwer_id
```

You will get :

```
ud1id = 1, u1name = john, u1status = 1, u2id = NULL, u2name = NULL, u2status = NULL
ud1id = 2, u1name = paul, u1status = 1, u2id = NULL, u2name = NULL, u2status = NULL
ud1id = 3, u1name = adam, u1status = 1, u2id = 1, u2name = john, u2status = 1
...
```

You also could get all values from `u1` and specific fields of `u2` :

```
select u1.*, u2.name as owner_name FROM ...
```

Comment: @Alvaro Louzada I've updated the anwser (correct tablename to `users` instead of `user`).

Comment: Works perfect THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

you can do directly in SQL   join user two time

```
  select  a.username, a.status, a.owner_id, b.username
  from user a
  left join user b  on b.id = a.owner_id
```